# posixct bug giving error for good date, good time, and good format

Tags: r, posixct

I made this code, and checked it and checked it, and I can't imagine why it gives me an error.

Code:

```
as.POSIXct(x = "2010-03-14 02:00:00", format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Error:

```
> as.POSIXct("2010-03-14 02:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] NA
```

I tried the help for the package.
I double-checked all the format flags.
I tried changing the date and the error went away.

Did a developer die or something on 3/14/2010?

Comment: most likely daylight savings time in your locale.

Comment: It has something to do with daylight saving time, google "2010 daylight saving time"

Comment: `as.POSIXct("2010-03-14 02:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2010-03-14 02:00:00 CET"` works for me, so defenitively problem on your local time